# Grid lines not uniform width

Tags: graphics, glsl, shader, webgl

I'm using the following fragment shader code to draw a grid:

```c
precision highp float;

uniform vec2 CANVAS_SIZE;
uniform float GRID_WIDTH;
uniform vec4 GRID_COLOR;

float isGridLine(float ordinate, float target, float halfThickness) {
    return step(ordinate, target + halfThickness) * step(target - halfThickness, ordinate);
}

void main() {
    vec2 uv = (gl_FragCoord.xy / CANVAS_SIZE);
    float halfGridWidth = GRID_WIDTH / 2.0;
    float gridLine = 0.0;
    for (float i = 0.0; i < 1.0; i += 0.05) {
        gridLine += isGridLine(uv.y, i, halfGridWidth);
        gridLine += isGridLine(uv.x, i, halfGridWidth);
    }
    gl_FragColor = mix(vec4(uv.rg, 0.0, 1.0), GRID_COLOR, step(1.0, gridLine));
}
```

The vertex shader simply creates a static mesh using vertex positions provided by the JavaScript code. It generates a single plane that fills the viewport.

```c
precision highp float;
attribute vec2 _vertexPosition;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(_vertexPosition, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

However, I've encountered an issue where every 5th grid line appears slightly thicker. Strangely, the fragment shader does not contain any specific logic for the 5th line.

Here are my observations so far:

I considered the possibility of the issue being related to float precision, but it persists regardless of using low or high precision.
I also tested the shader with different screen resolutions, but the discrepancy remains consistent.
Can anyone help me understand why these lines have different widths?

Image:

[image: WebGL Grid. Every 5th line thicker]

Comment: What happens if you change the .05 value to .025? Do you still get occasional thicker lines? What is their distribution?

Answer (score 0):

If you need a grid with lines of exactly 1 px wide, why don't you use something simpler like this code?

```
precision highp float;

uniform vec2 CANVAS_SIZE;
uniform float GRID_WIDTH;
uniform vec4 GRID_COLOR;

void main() {
    vec2 uv = (gl_FragCoord.xy / CANVAS_SIZE);
    float gridX = mod(gl_FragCoord.x, GRID_WIDTH);
    float gridY = mod(gl_FragCoord.y, GRID_WIDTH);
    vec4 background = vec4(uv.rg, 0.0, 1.0);
    fragColor = (gridX < 1.0) || (gridY < 1.0) ? GRID_COLOR : background;
}
```

[image]